# Combining detail namespace with anonymous namespace

Tags: c++, templates, namespaces, linkage

I'm writing template header and I have some stuff that doesn't belong to the library interface.
I know that putting these things into `detail` namespace is a good practice. The thing that bothers me is: should I put them also in anonymous namespace?

Comment: As far as I've ever seen, anonymous namespaces are used for 2 main reasons: 1) To force the reduction variable scope 2) To prevent function redefinitions when free functions in different files happen to share the same name

Comment: An anonymous namespace is nice in a source file, but not in a header included by multiple translation units.

Comment: @Cyber I think both reasons can be applied to this case.

Comment: Compilers also strip unused anonymous namespace symbols pretty early.  On the downside, it also stops `inline` collapsing of identical functions, which sucks if you don't have ICF.  On the upside, it stops accidental ODR violations.

Comment: @Yakk ICF: "identical COMDAT folding"? ODR: "One Definition Rule"?

Comment: @JonathanMee yep.  Without ICF, spamming identical copies of a function can bloat binaries with garbage.  `inline` (which `template`s and in-class methods include) risks ODR violation if something makes the implementation differ between compilation units.  ICF + `namespace{}` avoids ODR violations, and in cases where they are identical eliminates duplicates.  You still get surprises (function does something different in one compilation unit), but not insanity (order you build .o files changes behavior of application globally or semi-globally).